# Breakpoint on an exception in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

How do I set a breakpoint on an exception? 
Ideally I want to be able to see the call stack and local variables from the code that threw the exception.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I haven't used Visual Studio for 2 years, but from memory:

```
Ctrl + Alt + E
```

Will bring exception management screen, make sure to check break on all exceptions, a must have imho :)

**EDIT** : [My memory not that bad](http://www.dev102.com/2008/04/17/10-visual-studio-shortcuts-you-must-know/) :) Just check `Thrown` on `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` if your are using .NET (CLR = .NET)

**EDIT 2** : By the way, since exceptions are ***generally* a bad coding practice** and should be avoided as possible, i suggest to let that option enabled *all the time*. If some exceptions just can't be avoided *(because of someone else, of course :D)* just uncheck its type or ancestor in the exception type tree.

Comment: Exceptions **ARE NOT** bad coding practice

Comment: @abatishchev Added *generally* to my answer, seriously, I've seen enough atrocities implicating bad exception use. :)

Comment: Can't agree. **Generally - it's not!** But locally, in some, atrocious cases, it's really is.

Comment: @abatishchev, could discuss for a long time about this ;) anyway, advice, is still valid, if you have, let's say a `BusinessException`, you can exclude it from Exception Manager and keeping an eye while coding on all *unexpected* exceptions (which are the primary goal of.. *exceptions*...)

Comment: No doubt, your answer is absolutely correct. I was talking just about your comment :)

Comment: The problem is more with the people who badly use a language feature than the language feature itself.

Comment: Checking if things go wrong. Use tryparse instead of parse

Answer (score 9):

The exact visual studio command name is Debug.Exceptions

Main Menu > Debug > Exceptions (when solution is open)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 it's Main Menu > Debug > Windows > Exception Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure you're running in debug mode and that debugging is enabled in the project properties or else all the breakpoints in the world will count for nothing.

(Depending on your environment you can also click on the margin outside the code source to insert a breakpoint via mouse action)