# Exceptions debugging with async and UWP

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await, uwp, unhandled-exception

I'm working on the UWP application. And I'm using async/await a lot. Always when an exception occurs in my code the debugger set break in App.g.i.cs

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

But I want to see the line when the exception occured. How to achieve that behavior ?

Comment: You would have to handle the exception where it is thrown. For instance a try catch? Not sure what answer you are looking for here

Comment: May be that is XAML exception.

Comment: @Default, the problem is I don't know where  it is thrown and I want debuger to show it for me ))

Comment: @Janak, no, NullReferenceException for examle, in a view model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: How to break on handled exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions)

Comment: or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698154/force-break-on-any-exception-thrown-in-program) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183099/how-to-make-visual-studio-break-only-on-unhandled-exceptions) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597421/breakpoint-on-an-exception-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following method to your `App` class:

```
private static void UnhandledError(object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        // A breakpoint here is generally uninformative
        eventArgs.UnhandledError.Propagate();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Set a breakpoint here:
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

In your `App` constructor:

```
public UnitTestApp()
{
    CoreApplication.UnhandledErrorDetected += UnhandledError;

    // ...and any other initialization.
    // The InitializeComponent call just sets up error handlers,
    // and you can probably do without in the case of the App class.

    // This can be useful for debugging XAML:
    DebugSettings.IsBindingTracingEnabled = true;
    DebugSettings.BindingFailed +=
        (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Message);

}
```

There are still cases where you don't get a good stack trace, but this is often helpful.

Another approach is to break when an exception is thrown (via *Debug*, *Windows*, *Exception Settings*).

Comment: Thank you, it's very usefull !  But why debugger can't set break to expected line ?

Comment: Tell Visual Studio to break when (all or any specific) exception is thrown. The stack trace will provide the method, but not thw line.

Comment: Yes ! I've checked all Common Language Runtime Exceptions and not it's working ! Thank you.