# how to debug a c++ excel plugin's exception during excel exiting

Tags: c++, excel, plugins, visual-studio-debugging

I have an excel xll plug-in built in c++ (and with the help of [xlw](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/)), which, runs pretty well except, when excel exits, exception happens occasionally.

My headache is that though it looks like some destructor issue, I can't see where it went wrong.

Excel window just closes then a Windows system error message pops out.

Even if I run it in Visual Studio debug mode, when the exception happened, it's already in the STL c++ code, also I can't see which part of my code, such as a destructor, is the root cause of the failure.

To be precise, Call Stack shows
`[External Code]` -> `Excel.Exe` -> `[External Code]` -> `MSO.DLL` ... repeat... `OART.DLL`... repeat ... `ntdll.cll` -> `[External Code]` -> `_cexit()` -> `common_exit` -> `__acrt_lock_and_call` -> ...

The first step with source visible is `exit.cpp` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\startup\exit.cpp`,

```
extern "C" void __cdecl _cexit()
{
    common_exit(0, _crt_exit_full_cleanup, _crt_exit_return_to_caller);
}
```

Comment: Probably a global or static instance of some class of yours is being destroyed.  That's probably why you don't get a better call stack -- the runtime is doing the destruction due to global / static cleanup being done.  Either that or your program had already corrupted memory (during when you say it runs "pretty well"), and the results of that corruption is what you're seeing now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie probably, as there are really lots of global variables. how could I confirm that and isolate which one is the culprit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting a conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio settings to break on any exception (or the specific exception you are getting)? You can enable this just before you exit Excel. This might help track down the problem and give you the call stack in the call stack window when the breakpoint hits.

Also make sure to check if your symbol files (.pdb) are getting loaded for your code and any third party dependencies. Another thing that can help is to specify the Microsoft public symbol servers so that the Microsoft system pdb’s are loaded as well as mentioned in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx).

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597421/breakpoint-on-an-exception-in-visual-studio

Comment: @athos are you getting a good stack trace in the call stack window. This article might help setup your debugging environment properly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxtecharts/debugging-with-symbols

Comment: i added destructors for those global variables' classes, and turned on the exception setting as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597421/breakpoint-on-an-exception-in-visual-studio , it turned out that when excel is quitting, a global map variable's destructor is called, and, STL code seems doing a loop on iterator and delete, unfortunately the deleting actually set the iterator to an invalid status. I wrapped the `map<string,Foo>` into a `FooMap` class, and in `~FooMap()` did a `if(this->size()>0) this->clear();` seems solved the issue.

Comment: @athos Glad to know that you solved your issue. If my answer helped please upvote and/or mark it as the accepted answer so it can help others who may face the same issue.